# WPF MVVM cancel Window.Closing event

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

In WPF application together with MVVMLight Toolkit, I would like to see your opinion, what is the best way to implement if I need to Cancel the Window Close event.
In Window.Closing event I can set the e.Cancel = true, which prevents closing the form. To identify if the Close is allowed, or should be prevented is in the ViewModel context.

One solution could be if I define an Application variable, and I can query this in the normal event handler in view code behind?

thanks

Comment: In normal MVVM it's straight-forward with an attached property.  No clue how it works with MVVMLight though...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With MVVM Light you got `EventToCommand`:

So you could in xaml wire up the closing event to the VM.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and in the VM:

```
public RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> ClosingCommand { get; private set; }

ctor() {
  ClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(args => args.Cancel = true);
}
```

**If you do not want to pass `CancelEventArgs` to the VM**:

You could always take the similar approach with a `Behavior` and just use a simple `bool` from the VM(bind this bool to the Behavior) to indicate the closing event should be cancelled.

**Update:**

[Download Link for following example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2x7e6nphp7pg5s6/MVVMCancelCloseWindow.rar)

To do this with a `Behavior` you could just have a `Behavior` such as:

```
internal class CancelCloseWindowBehavior : Behavior<Window> {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CancelCloseProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CancelClose", typeof(bool),
      typeof(CancelCloseWindowBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

  public bool CancelClose {
    get { return (bool) GetValue(CancelCloseProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CancelCloseProperty, value); }
  }

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    AssociatedObject.Closing += (sender, args) => args.Cancel = CancelClose;
  }
}
```

Now in xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <local:CancelCloseWindowBehavior CancelClose="{Binding CancelClose}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Where `CancelClose` is a bool property from the VM which indicates if the `Closing` event should be cancelled or not. In the attached example I have a `Button` to toggle this bool from the VM that should let you test the `Behavior`

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution, but I would like to keep the advantage of the MVVM to separate the View and Model as much as it is possible.
How to handle this with Behavior? If I use bool value is the window close event can be cancelled?

Comment: @pillesoft Check the update at the end of the answer for an example to do it with a `Behavior`. There is also a download link that should give you the example in a project to test. One thing as a side-note to keep in mind is, the main advantage of MVVM over patterns like MVC is allowing the VM code to be unit-tested. So if you can unit test your logic in the VM fine(which you can in this case with a unit test project) I personally wouldn't instantly brand an approach as wrong.

Comment: can i use MVVM light approach to pass an argument along the eventArgs like this?  <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                            />

Comment: Behavior did the trick for me, however if you have `InvokeCommandAction` and behavior for on Closing event, then the Behavior is invoked first.

Answer (score 0):

You could to control this using `Messages`, for instance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<CloseApplicationMessage>(this, m => Close());
        Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;
        Closing += MainWindowClosing;
    }

    private void MainWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Ask for saving
        var closingMessage = new ClosingApplicationMessage();
        Messenger.Default.Send(closingMessage);
        if (closingMessage.Cancel)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
...
```

The mvvm message:

```
public class ClosingApplicationMessage
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, in any place you are listening to the `ClosingApplicationMessage`, you can control when the application is going to close, and may to cancel it.
Hope this helps...