# Handling window closing in WPF - MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to handle the window closing using a solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23614156/8808164), but the handler in my ViewModel is firing on application start, and not when closing.

XAML:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowClosing}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs> WindowClosing
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs>((args) => {});
    }
}
```

The binding is obviously functioning, but it's just firing at exactly the wrong time. I thought the EventName="Closing" is what was supposed to bind to the actual closing event, but it doesn't matter what's contained there. It always fires on loading. What exactly is supposed to link this to the actual window closing event?

Comment: See the eventtrigger? This is something that happens when a routed event happens. In this case, the closing event is specified by eventname. IMO, it's of doubtful value to make this a command and decouple using an eventtrigger. If you just handled window closing in code behind of the view you could cast the datacontext and call a method in the viewmodel.

Comment: This is the solution im working with now, I used an interface to avoid casting the datacontext directly to the videomodel per some advice. Im not quite sure how that works, is the datacontext just a reference to whatever its set to?

Comment: Datacontext is a dependency property of type object. It can be set to an instance of your viewmodel or inherit that from a parent. Because it's object you need to cast it to something and yes that can be an interface. The view "not knowing" about what viewmodel it connects to is often rather academic though. Usually it's just viewmodels you're going to instantiate and exercise tests on. Imo the decider in favour of the dependency property would be if you want to switch out viewmodels. That's unusual though and often you have one view and one viewmodel which you know the type of.